# Folium unable to add multiple points with "same" icon

Tags: python, folium

I'm having trouble adding multiple markers with same icon style in folium.

First I declared icon:

```
icon_blue = folium.Icon(color='blue', icon_color='white', icon='info-sign')
```

Later on I wrote

```
folium.Marker(
    location=latlng_start,
    popup=text_start,
    tooltip=text_start,
    name=text_start,
    icon=icon_blue,
).add_to(map1)

folium.Marker(
    location=latlng_end,
    popup=text_end,
    tooltip=text_end,
    name=text_end,
    icon=icon_blue,
).add_to(map1)
```

And when I do this, I get output like:

[image]

Basically, a singleton point, with no tooltip or any data attached to it.

The issue disappears when I delete `icon=icon_blue` but it also disappears if I make a copy of `icon_blue`:

```
icon_blue_copy = folium.Icon(color='blue', icon_color='white', icon='info-sign')
```

And then for the second one write:

```
folium.Marker(
    location=latlng_end,
    popup=text_end,
    tooltip=text_end,
    name=text_end,
    icon=icon_blue_copy,
).add_to(map1)
```

To get desired output

[image]

The problem is, why do I need to make these copies? is this some sort of Folium bug, or is this something to do with python?

Comment: I also experimented with it. I couldn't use the same icon definition as in the question. My guess is that it is designed not to accept the same object ID. In [this example](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Markers), markers with the same icon settings but different latitude and longitude are displayed, so I think this is the case. As a conclusion, I guess you need to set an icon for each marker.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug, but has not been solved yet. https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining,

> ```
> icon_blue = folium.Icon(color='blue', icon_color='white', icon='info-sign')
> ```

setting the icon inside the marker as,

```
folium.Marker(
  location=latlng_end,
  popup=text_end,
  tooltip=text_end,
  name=text_end,
  icon=folium.Icon(color='blue', 
                   icon_color='white', 
                   icon='info-sign')
).add_to(map1)
```

worked for me.